# What's Flow State, and what does it mean to the SE community?

Tags: discussion, blog, events

I recently became aware that Stack Exchange is running a conference called [Flow State](https://flowstate.stackoverflow.co). The banner on Stack Overflow says:

> Register to virtually attend our inaugural conference focused on our products, with relevant content for all developers everywhere.

A cursory look at MSO, and well I'm an MSE mod so, a less cursory look at MSE shows that there's literally no mention of this apart from the blog. Stack's supposed to be a little more knowledge worker centric than purely dev centric but consider how this [post on Joel Spolsky's blog about the 2009 edition](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2009/05/12/stack-overflow-devdays/) - it talks about specific things and what would be interesting to the target audience of the time, and what's essentially the elevator pitch for that is on [tech crunch](https://techcrunch.com/2011/06/24/stack-exchange-gets-into-the-conference-game-with-stack-overflow-devdays/). I'm wondering what's the equivalent for this as far as the community or non specifically invited folks are concerned?

From the looks of the thing, and the language used and some of the FAQs, it's almost like it's felt like the community is an afterthought. In many cases, these would be the folks who'd be the subject matter experts in these tools should they be adopted.

From the [Flow State FAQ](https://flowstate.stackoverflow.co/#faq):

> **I’m a Stack Overflow public community member. Can I attend?**
>
> We love interacting with members of the community! You are welcome to
> register and attend our virtual live stream. Keep in mind that the
> presentations at this event will center around challenges and
> solutions for large-scale organizations and not our public platform.
> Product presentations will specifically focus on Stack Overflow paid
> products and features.
>
> **Will there be a Stack Overflow community event?**
>
> Nothing is currently scheduled, but we are always looking for new and
> exciting ways to engage with the community.

Feels like it's more designed around 'management' sorts who might not be familiar with the network sites, SO included. This also seems at odds with "relevant content with all developers". I'm going to assume the 'invited' guests, virtual or physical would know what it is about, but what's the specific intended audience, and the pitch for this?

Even virtually - What would be the 'benefit' of someone who's a public Q&A user, and a non decision making knowledge worker to keep up with events of the conference and what would be relevant for us?

If it's primarily focused on business - are there any plans for community centric events?

Comment: From reading the short description I'd assume that this is mostly a sales pitch for Teams.

Comment: Just quoting this: "*For additional information, feel free to contact us at flowstate@stackoverflow.com*"

Comment: Make sure to read the [Agenda](https://flowstate.stackoverflow.co/agenda), there are hints about what's going to take place, and the link to it isn't very obvious. (Top right of the screen, where we usually expect to see something else)

Comment: @RandomPerson sure, but since it's SE-related, we can and better ask here as well.

Comment: @RandomPerson sure - if you were an individual interested in the conference. I'm more asking this cause, well there's a general lack of communication with the community about this, and its not about communication with "me" but rather well, everyone here or MSO, depending.

Comment: I just found it frustrating that it states it has relevant content for all devs everywhere, when after digging in more it's... well, not that at all. Seemingly more of the same stretching of the truth to present a convenient message. I don't have a problem with this event occurring or it being about what it's about, or even being informed of it via a banner.. just get the messaging fixed before stuff like this goes out.

Comment: By the way, the psychological concept of [flow state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) ("a person performing some activity is fully immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity") was popularized by Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi; see e.g. the TED talk, [Flow, the secret to happiness](https://www.ted.com/talks/mihaly_csikszentmihalyi_flow_the_secret_to_happiness).